# Does my breast size decrease permanently after weight loss?

Tags: weight-loss, bellyfat

I have been running for a while now and dieting, and I've lost a couple of pounds of weight. I'm now 130 lbs and 5 foot 11, and 25 years old. As a result, my breast size has also decreased.

I've heard that you lose more of your breast fat if you're on a calorie deficit, than what you gain if you're on a calorie surplus.

In other words, I've heard that if you lose 5 pounds, and then gain 5 pounds, you will have relatively less fat in your breasts in the end than before you lost the 5 pounds, and relatively more in your belly.

Is this true? is there scientific evidence for this, or for it being false?

Comment: I cannot answer your question.  I applaud your discipline, but please note that 130 lb at 5'11" is very thin. You might be healthier at a higher bodyweight.

Answer (score 2):

A pound of fat lost from breast tissue is no different than a pound of fat anywhere else in your body.

Females tend to accumulate fat around the hips, buttocks, and thighs while men have a larger intra-abdominal (visceral) fat mass.

Diet and genetics also have major roles in determining the proportion and site of fat storage.  Fertility hormones (leptin, oestrogen), ovarian function seem to mainly signal a general increase in lipogenesis and storage (in the predisposed areas mentioned above).

Simply put if it was there before I see no reason why it would no longer return to that area.  See if you're able to find supporting research.  Use the search box at NIH.

---

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17977473
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11706283
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11706283